# How to echo output in one line?

Tags: php

I have a script, and it working fine. However the output is in multiple lines. How can I fix this to output into a single line?

```
 <?php
 $filename1 = './workspace/vars1.txt';
 $contents1 = file($filename1);
 foreach ($contents1 as $line1) {
     $str1 = " <TR><TD>$line1:</TD><TD> <input type=\"text\"name \"$line1\" " ;
     echo $str1;
     fwrite($file, $str1);
 }
 fclose($file);
 ?>
```

The output:

```
<TR><TD>ID
:</TD><TD> <input type="text"name="ID
"  <TR><TD>APP
:</TD><TD> <input type="text"name="APP
"
```

The output should be:

```
<TR><TD>ID:</TD><TD> <input type="text"name="ID"  <TR><TD>APP:</TD><TD> <input type="text"name="APP"
```

Comment: Most likely those values contain line break characters in them. Have a try using the `trim()` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be your value contain spaces. trim it then display it.

```
 foreach ($contents1 as $line1) {
 $line1 = trim($line1);
 $str1 = " <TR><TD>$line1:</TD><TD> <input type=\"text\"name=\"$line1\" " ;
 echo $str1;
 fwrite($file, $str1);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

When the `file()` function reads the lines from a file, it also includes the new line characters. We simply need to remove them:

```
foreach ($contents1 as $line1) {
    // Remove any new line characters from the string before using it.
    $line1 = str_replace(PHP_EOL, '', $line1);  
    $str1 = " <TR><TD>$line1:</TD><TD> <input type=\"text\"name=\"$line1\" " ;
    echo $str1;
    fwrite($file, $str1);
}
```